# EFCodeFirst ctp 5 composite primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

Is there a way to create a composite key in efcodefirst with code(model) first.

atm I have this

```
 [Key]
    public string ResourceType { get; set; }
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }
    public string ResourceValue { get; set; }
```

I need resourcetype+resourcekey to be the composite key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composite Key with EF 4.1 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466374/composite-key-with-ef-4-1-code-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is the same as presented here 
[Composite Key with EF 4.1 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466374/composite-key-with-ef-4-1-code-first)