# Is it a new trend to create database table using a surrogate monotonous increasing int as PK?

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

A lot of example of code-first shows that the PK of the table is XXXXXID, if the XXXXX matches the entity name; otherwise the ORM will create the PK using the columns ending with "ID". (Maybe it will create combined key for many-to-many relationship).

What if the entity already have a natural key? Maybe code first should be avoid if a sound database design is required?

Comment: I'd hardly call it a new trend - ever since MS Access offered to add a primary key if you didn't define one, and did so by creating a column called ID using a sequence, a lot of people have thought that the two concepts are synonymous.

Comment: If your table **really** has a good, natural key (that is narrow, unique, stable) - then by all means, use it. And EF code-first doesn't make this impossible - not at all. [You can easily decorate such a given property with the `[Key]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx) to mark it as the primary key of an entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @marc_s described in the comment you can use your own key (even [composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466374/composite-key-with-ef-4-1-code-first/5468507#5468507)) but you must remember that EF is little bit more restrictive for key usage. You cannot change PK value for existing entity - the key in EF is immutable. The only time when you can define value for PK is before you insert it to the database.