# Code first vs. Code only

Tags: .net, entity-framework

What is the difference between Code first and Code only approaches? Are these two names for the same thing or not?

Comment: Code *first* implies that you will do something else, whereas code *only* implies that you will not do anything once you're done coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two names for the same thing.  See http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

This post/question will help you [Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first)