# Differences in EF Code FIrst and Database first model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new in EF and trying to understand the differences in EF Code First and Database first model. What should be the best choice for starting a new MVC3 project?

Comment: I think the **code** first and **database** first should exactly describe the difference unless you didn't start programming this morning. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first/5446587#5446587) you have something about differences between database / model / code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pros and cons of EF Code first and database first model, view following posts. It definitely helps you.

[Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first)

[EF 4.1 Model & Database First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx)

[Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting a new project and do not have a current database then code first is the easiest way to get started.

If you are starting a new project but already have a database that you are building around you would then use Database first.