# Entity Framework DBContext Databinding Issues

Tags: c#, binding, entity-framework-4.1, entity

Using VS2010, C#, Winforms and Entity Framework 4.1

Here is my code

```
var order = dbContext.Orders.Where(o=>o.OrderId == 1).Single();
var orderDetails = order.OrderDetails.ToList():

textBox1.Bindings.Add("Text", order, "OrderAmount");
gridView.DataSource = orderDetails;
```

I have following two questions about Entity Framework 4.1

1. If I update an entity property, the new value is not reflected to the UI.
2. I want to add logic to an entity property setter; but it gets rewritten each time the model is updated.

Thanks.

Comment: My Winforms knowledge is poor. But I think you should check some refreshing properties of your visual component (as I understood a new record appeared in the database).

Answer (score 0):

About the second question. 
Automatic updating of classes is how the model first works. 
You can read [EF 4.1 Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first) for more information. 
 
 Sometimes it's convenient to modify the [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). But I don't recommend to change getters/setters. Instead adding some dataannotations attributes could be useful. You can read how to use it on MSDN: 
 [Using Data Annotations to Customize Data Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) 
 [How to: Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use the on property change inside of the databinding

textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",order,"OrderAmount",true,System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);