# Entity Framework, Entity Model creation clarification

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn **ASP.NET MVC** + **Entity Framework** by developing a small project. I have created basic structure of Database as required & now trying to Connect database to the MVC project.

When I check few MVC EF tutorials, There are two methods to create entity classes to map Database *(as I understood)* :

1. Creating EDMX file using existing database
2. Creating Entity Classes manually as required

What I need to clarify is whether there is any difference in using these methods (limitations, advantages, or disadvantages)?

Sorry if I'm asking something very simple or irrelevant...

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first.  Also, there are technically 3 approaches, as the accepted answer explains

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks for the link. I guess what I'm doing is "Database first" so what if I create the entities manually, is it unnecessary? and if I create EDMX file can I add business logic to the same classes generated by the VS?

Comment: You can create the entities manually, sure.  But why would you do that over using generated partial classes?  And modifying the generated classes is usually a bad idea, because you can't safely regenerate them upon modifying the database.  You would either create a customized T4 template or a partial class for your business logic.  The link above deals with all this, by the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check :

- [Demystifying Entity Framework Strategies: Model Creation Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148150.aspx)
- [Update to Data Points Column](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/model-first-database-first-or-code-first-ndash-update-to-data-points-column/)
- [Is Entity Framework Code First really third distinct option?](http://blog.cincura.net/232371-is-entity-framework-code-first-really-third-distinct-option/)

All these will teach you about options how to approach Entity Framework's model.