# Database first with Reverse Enginer code first does not generated edmx?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

i've created a database in sql server. After that, i choose to use Entity Framework for the first time of my life. Reading a few posts here, i used the Reverse Engine Code First and it created all my models from my database. Works great, but always when i'm trying to understand a problem, peoples says about the edmx, which i dont have. Why?
What is the real best way to design a database first and use the EF after?
For example, i dont know how to update my models after changing the base. I always need to run the Reverse Engine Code First Tool again, wich messed with a lot of other things.
I'm really loose, and sorry for this post if has another one equals. I tried to search but dont know the right terms to search. Its my first time with EF5.

Thanks

Comment: You update the models by writing the code/mappings according to the changes you introduced in the DB or (as you noticed) re-running the EF Power Tools. Easy enough, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.1 Code-first vs Model/Database-first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/ef-4-1-code-first-vs-model-database-first)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor but my doubt is about i'm right doing that or not :( its sounds strange for me sometimes, because everybody talk about an edmx wich i dont have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDMX files are used when you have Database First and want to use as ADO Dataset.

Comment: Its common to use EF + Ado? Isnt linq better to that?

Comment: I presume you mean LinqToSql? LinqToSql is generally not regarded as performant as EF and was I believe designed with web services data access layers in mind.  An EDMX file is primarily used with a designer in Visual Studio and lets you connect to a database and drag tabels and stored procedures into the view to build a data context.  Code-first if more about  writing objects which EF then turns into a database.  You don't need an EDMX file to make use of EF.

Comment: Thanks, its all new to me :(

Comment: No problem, it's a lot to get your head around :)