# Work flow using Code-First -vs- DB-First in starting a new project? EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When creating a new solution (typically ASP.Net MVC or API) I usually create a data access project and my web project. In the data access project I typically use EF6 and have been trying to use Code-First so that I can take advantage of the migrations feature.

In the data access project I create a model folder and then in that folder add my classes and my DBContext class. Then I generate my migrations and seed data. This all works ok.

- What I was wondering are there more efficient ways of creating this
  type of project?
- Am I hampering my productivity by going code first?
- I know I am not using code generation that the database first process
  would use. Can I gain efficiencies by switching to DB first?
- What are typical work flows that others use?
- OR is there a hybrid approach that people find successful?

I understand that this has been addressed in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first) but my questions is more in context of EF6 and those all seem to be based on EF4.

TIA

Comment: Just added to my question to further clarify. That particular article is EF4 based. I'm wondering if things have changed between 4 and 6

Comment: Lots of answers to this but immediately I think:  Do the tables already exist?  And do I need much by way of POCO's or business rules on the model itself?  If the answers are Yes->No respectively then DB first is probably more desired since it creates your models for you.

Comment: @EvanL - you can create a Code First model from the database as well - EF 6.1 tooling supports this.

Comment: @Pawel Honestly haven't worked with EF6 yet.  Good to know!

Comment: @EvanL - take a look at this then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: @Pawel Thanks!  I will read up =)