# change in DB changes code in Mvc 5 code first approach using EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first

I am going to use Code First Approach and I am slightly confused whether changes in Database will change the code in MVC 5 code first approach using EF 6

And I am also refered the 
[Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first)

Please help me understand with this

Comment: The Code First Approach would generally mean that the structure of your database is based on your code, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

No change in database will not change your code in code first.
But if you have any changes in your POCO classes used for tables then your database will change.