# Connection to SQL Server database files requires SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2008 asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. When I try to add a SQL Server database to the mvc solution in Visual Studio, it gives me following error:

> Connection to sql server database files require sql server 2005 express or sql server 2008 asp net

Any thoughts?

Comment: Because you don't connect to database. You creating **database file**, which is part of the project. And for that you need Express version.

Comment: @T.S. Thanks. But why do I need express version if I already have the regular version?

Comment: Again. You said *When I try to add a SQL Server Database to the mvc solution* - you're adding db file to your project. DB file is different beast. Full version of Sql Server doesn't work with it.  Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first

Comment: The ability to have "free-floating" `.mdf` that you connect to using `AttachDbFileName=......` in your connection string in an **Express-only** feature. The **proper solution** is to create the database **on the SQL Server** and reference it only using it's logical name and stop fiddling around with `.mdf` files - let SQL SErver handle that ....

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

On 64-bit systems this error can be caused by 32/64 bit mismatch between Visual Studio and SQL Server  Express. Microsoft published a fix regarding this issue, hope it helps:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957944