# Repositories calling existing stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, architecture, repository-pattern

Let's say I am developing a few ASP.NET MVC applications working with data in an existing database just over by stored procedures, no and never linq to entities or anything else. That database contains lots of schemas and all my web applications needs the different schemas as well.

Here is my point:

- I have a x.Model project in my solution that contains my ADO.NET Entity Model to create return types for all of my stored procedures in my existing db.
- I have x.Repository.y projects in my solution where y is the schema name in the database. These projects contains classes having functions to call the stored procedures from the appropriate schema by ADO.NET Entity Model's context. So I have to have reference of x.Model in these repository projects.
- And I have ASP.NET MVC projects that uses the necessary injected repositories from x.Repository.y projects. I use some of these return types of stored procedures as models in my views, so I need a reference to x.Model project too. But in that case this reference gives all the context to client web applications. I don't want my whole or partial db entities is reachable in my web applications. I just want them to know about necessary repository classes.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

If I remove x.Model project and create the ADO.NET Entity Models containing just the appropriate schemas stored procedures in my x.Repository.y projects then the referencing web applications again knows about this schema's whole db entities.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, better way to use [Model First or Code First approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first). So, you can describe pure (without references to DbContext and other Data classes) entities. Then, create mapping in x.Repository project. And referene your Model to ASP.NET MVC site. So, you will have only entities and repositories but mapping and DbContext will be hidden inside one reference (you can mark [mapping classes](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) as `internal`).