# Entity framework - switch from database first to model first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and I started with database first. I want to know if it is possible to change it to switch to model first. My database already exists and I want be able to change it from the model.
Is it possible ?

Comment: There is an option in Visual Studio when creating a new Entity data model `Generate from database` - this could be a way to go.

Comment: but if I using it, can I change the model and it will change the database?

Comment: I suppose it can generate an empty database from your model. About changing I am not sure, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5446587/2224701

Comment: Here is a pretty thorough walk through: http://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/