# EF Code First (generated) vs EDMX

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, edmx, ef-database-first

About working with already existing databases, I never found any clear comparison between EF Code First (Generated model) and EF Database First (EDMX) approaches.

I'm tending more to use Code First, but it's not quite clear to me if there's still any disavantage of using this approach vs the EDMX approach.

Is there any reason I shouldn't use EF Code First Generated model for existing databases?

Comment: You'll probably get hammered on your question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) but plenty of opinions out there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first

Comment: I`ve already seen that question, but it doesn't answer my question clearly. What I want to know is: Why shouldn't I use Code First for existing databases?