# What is the use of code-first approach

Tags: entity-framework

I am wondering how the code-first approach in EF will be the best approach over db first. Can you please clarify me what is the use of code-first approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually the best approach. Choosing between `code first` or `db first` can be based on a project or developers skills. You can read more about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first) on the stackoverflow.