# Should we use the entities generated by entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Hello I use entity framework with a unit of work pattern and I would like to know if in my application layer I should work directly with entities generated by entity framework or recreate POCO objects in my application layer and map my POCO?

Because I would like my application layer not to make any reference to my entities, I would like for example to create another project in my solution that could map my entities to my poco in my application but I don't know if this is a good practice and especially I don't know how to do it

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first)

Comment: It depends on... Do you have information in your ef-classes, that should not been shown in your application? What kind of application is it?...

Comment: It is an asp.net mvc application.
I'm going to have to use all the information except in my view model

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my `UnitOfWork` I have used a generic repository pattern that uses the models generated by the EF directly. The `IRepository<T>` interface looks a bit like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    T GetById(long Id); 
     //etc - all the stuff you probably have
 }
```

I have implementation of the `IRepository` called `Repository`

```
public Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
     public readonly Infomaster _dbContext;

     public Repository(Infomaster dbContext)
      {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
       }

     public void Add(T entity)
     {
         _dbContext.Set<T>.Add(t);
     }
}
```

The use of the set and the type allows me to access the dataset (`dbSet`) of that particular type which allows me to create a generic pattern. You can use specific classes but it's a lot more work.
This means in my `UnitOfWork`, I only need to do the following:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
     //Db context 
     Infomaster _dbContext;

     //User is a model from my EF
     public IRepository<User> UserRepository { get; private set; }

     public UnitOfWork()
     {
         _dbContext = new Infomaster();

          UserRepository = new Repository<User>(_dbContext);
     }

     public int Commit()
     {
          return _dbContext.Save(); 
     }
}
```

I find that is the best way and requires the use of the model classes, I am using a code first database but I have done with database first.

(from iPhone - can and will update from laptop)