# C# - Use a Generic & Template Type to Add an Identifier Property to any Class

Tags: c#, templates, generics, crud

Got an idea that's been in my head for a while, and I'm at the point where it would benefit my current project if I could find a way to implement it.

I'm building out an API that has a ton of CRUD functionality, specifically a lot of Add/Edit stuff that is, for all intents and purposes, doing the same operations but just with or without an ID to indicate an existing record.

For example, here is what gets posted to the API to add a new address:

```
public class AddressDto
{
  public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
  public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string County { get; set; }
  public string Postcode { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

And here is what gets posted to the API to update an existing address:

```
public class ExistingAddressDto
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
  public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string County { get; set; }
  public string Postcode { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

As you can see, basically the same thing, just with an extra `Id` field. This obviously isn't an issue when just considering these two classes, but it's becoming clearer as the codebase grows that we're going to have a huge number of duplicate DTO's for very little benefit. We've experimented with inheriting a base class that adds just the `Id` field, but even this leads to declaring extra classes.

I wondered if it would be possible to build out a generic type that could be wrapped around another class, and add an `Id` property onto whatever was passed to it as the template. Something like this:

```
//declaration 
public class Existing<T> where T : class
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public T Value { get; set; } //ideally would love to not have this as a nested property
}

//in use
var existingAddress = new Existing<AddressDto>();
```

I feel like the idea can work in theory, but what I'm trying to see is if it's possible to have `Id` on the same level as properties of the templated object. At present, you would access the properties like this:

```
var id = existingAddress.Id;
var city = existing.Value.City;
```

I think what I'm looking for is something like being able to use JavaScript's "spread" operator, or some equivalent, but not sure if this part is possible or how to implement it.

Any advice on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: "as the codebase grows that we're going to have a huge number of duplicate DTO's for very little benefit." That's why you should consider to just auto-generate these things from your database or from any external schema-definition.

Comment: *"We've experimented with inheriting a base class that adds just the Id field, but even this leads to declaring extra classes."* So what's wrong with having those extra classes? I guess you could have a source generator to make them for you to save on the typing.

Comment: @DavidG Fair question. I appreciate what you're saying, but I think looking into whether this generic/template approach is viable could produce an outcome where one class can be written that could be applied to any DTO within the solution. Creating duplicative classes isn't a huge hardship but I think it's worth investigation whether the codebase can be streamlined a little.

Comment: What type of API is this? With that knowledge we might have options to ease the pain. But purely on the class level like you show you presumably need a different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd approach these kinds of problems is with source generation. Specifically for your case, I'd parse all classes that end with `Dto` (and don't start with `Existing`) and create a class for each called `Existing<name>Dto` with the same fields and an additional `Id` field as you describe.

This way you get no inheritance, no nested fields and no reflection, just plain code that's kept up to date by your compiler.

Answer (score -1):

> as the codebase grows that we're going to have a huge number of duplicate DTO's for very little benefit.

Sure, but that shouldn't be a problem, when you generate these classes automatically, e.g. from your database, a service-description or whatever external API-specification. There are more or less two different appraoches to achieve consitency between your code and your database: the database-first-approach and the code-first approach. See [Code-first vs Model/Database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446316/code-first-vs-model-database-first) for differences between these two. There's also something like "description" or "schema" first, which indicates that you have some schema-definition like an XML-file and create your tabase as well as the code from it.

Whichever you chose, you should create the other parts of your system automatically, to avoid inconsitencies and all these annoying changes you described above.

Comment: Don't auto-generate code from your database, it's not version controlled. I've tried it and it was just a plain mess.

Comment: @Blindy that depends on where your root of your knowledge is located. I agree about the source-control-stuff, however that pattern is highly used in existing legacy-products, that unfortunately often don't start with a code-first-approach. Having said this, the databaswe-first-appraoch can often be replaced by the other.

Comment: "that pattern is highly used in existing legacy-products" -- don't take inspiration from legacy products. Really, the problem you'll encounter the most with this approach is that you can never run any older version of your product, since your DB-backed fields have changed since then. And if you try to rebuild them they won't compile again, because the code in source control will automagically change based on your DB, but its usage won't. That defeats the purpose of source control. Again, a mess.